# Problem with Facebook sync - All instead of existing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, sync, facebook

I have a problem when time comes to sync my Facebook friends with existing contact. Even if I select "Sync with existing contact" in the app, **all** my Facebook friends are added to my local contact, like if I'd chosen "Sync all". But the options works 'cause as soon as I select "Do not sync", everything from Facebook disappear from my contact on my phone.Is anyone else having this problem, or a solution perhaps?

By the way, my phone is a Galaxy S2 running ICS (4.0.3) with the latest version of Facebook (1.9.7). Everything use to be all right before... I don't know which update messed up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this new update from Facebook. You need to go to `Settings | Apps | All apps`, search for Facebook, tap the entry, and then "Uninstall updates". This option is only available if your phone came with the Facebook app, not if you installed it yourself. Then try sync again. I'm skipping the latest version of Facebook; the one before worked just fine.

Comment: Damn! In my "troubleshooting process", I've uninstall then reinstall Facebook...so I don't have the previous version :( I'll wait and wish that updates will come fast!

Answer (score 0):

If this is still a problem, you can download an older version of Facebook that doesn't have the quirk you are currently encountering.